# VBA: Loop to map figures from 2 different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have 2 different excel workbooks, one is called DATA and one is called ReportTemplate. So now i need to insert data from DATA to corresponding row/column in ReportTemplate.

How I am doing now is, for example:
'Others ( this is for other currencies)

```
DATA_FILE.activate
Sheets("SA_FX_2").select
SRC_SA_FX_2_D25 = Range("D25").Value
SRC_SA_FX_2_E25 = Range("E25").Value
SRC_SA_FX_2_F25 = Range("F25").Value
SRC_SA_FX_2_G25 = Range("G25").Value
SRC_SA_FX_2_H25 = Range("H25").Value

REPORTTEMPLATE_FILE.activate
Sheets("SA_FX_2").select
Range("D36").Value = SRC_SA_FX_2_D25
Range("E36").Value = SRC_SA_FX_2_E25
Range("F36").Value = SRC_SA_FX_2_F25
Range("G36").Value = SRC_SA_FX_2_G25
Range("H36").Value = SRC_SA_FX_2_H25
```

The SRC_SA_FX_2_X25 is to store the values for that particular cells in DATA, then insert it into Range("X36").Value in REPORTTEMPLATE. So currently I am doing the "mapping" in a hard-coded way.

This is how my DATA looks like:
[DATA TEMPLATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni4qz.png)

And this is how my REPORTTEMPLATE looks like:[REPORTTEMPLATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REa7I.png)

For the "Others" and above currencies, they are all fixed, so I can just hard code the cells.

However, if there is any new currency, my macro should detect that, then choose the currency in the drop down list, and do the mapping.

How can I actually parameterize my codes above in order to the mapping for the rest of the currencies?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to `MATCH` them like:

```
'we look for rows 3 to 5 of DATA_FILE in REPORTTEMPLATE_FILE
Dim i As Long, OutRow As Variant, wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
Set wsIn = DATA_FILE.Sheets("SA_FX_2")
Set wsOut = REPORTTEMPLATE_FILE.Sheets("SA_FX_2")
For i = 3 To 5
  'get the row of the active item in REPORTTEMPLATE_FILE
  OutRow = Application.Match(wsIn.Cells(i, 3).Value2, wsOut.Columns(3), 0)
  If Not IsNumeric(OutRow) Then OutRow = Application.Match("-- Please Select Currency --", wsOut.Columns(3), 0) 'not there -> new line
  wsOut.Range("C" & OutRow & ":H" & OutRow).Value2 = wsIn.Range("C" & i & ":H" & i).Value2
Next
```

Just change the `For i = 3 To 5` to fit your needs and check, if the `"-- Please Select Currency --"` does match.

If you have any questions or problems, just ask ;)

Comment: hi Dirk, I am trying to understand this
OutRow = Application.Match(wsIn.Cells(i, 3).Value2, wsOut.COLUMNS(3), 0). So this is trying to match wsIn.cells(i,3).value2 to wsOut.columns(3), but what does the .value2 and 0 behind mean?

Comment: @Chun `Value2` simply is the value inside the cell. And the `0` is to match exactly (either find exactly the same, or return an error).

Comment: when i tired to debug the outrow = application.match... is giving me outRow = Error 2042, and the wsout.Range = wsIn.Range is giving me type mismatch. what could be the problem causing this?

Comment: @Chun The first `Match` should only return an error if it is not in the list. And the second one *theoretically* never should error. Please check if the strings are correct (the currencies need to be exactly the same, no extra spaces or something like that). Also the "Please Select Currency" needs to match. If that all is correct and you still get errors, please tell me.

Comment: hi yes it works, i also changed the for i = x to y to Do Until the cell = " " so it will quit. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Dirk, i tried to use above method to do the similar thing, but now i am just directly mapping. eg, SOURCE_FILE D2 to I2 to TARGET_FILE A9 TO F9. THEN D3 to I3 to A10 to F10. i tried using for i = 2 to 20, j = 9 to 27, but it will loop the j first until j is finished looping, but that is not what i want. Do you have any suggestion? i would say this is quite a simple job but i just can't make it work. thanks!